# How to force Solr to build spatial heatmap in bounds that won't differ from bounds specified in the request?

Tags: solr, heatmap, markerclusterer

Here is an example of Solr heatmap response:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "params": {
            "q": "*:*",
            "facet.heatmap": "location_p",
            "facet.heatmap.geom": "[\"0.6247379779815674 51.52351760864258\" TO \"5.051644802093506 51.570556640625\"]",
            "facet.heatmap.distErrPct": "0.28",
            "facet": "true",
            "wt": "json"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 5876,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [
            // docs...
        ]
    },
    "facet_counts": {
        "facet_queries": {},
        "facet_fields": {},
        "facet_ranges": {},
        "facet_intervals": {},
        "facet_heatmaps": {
            "location_p": [
                "gridLevel",
                4,
                "columns",
                14,
                "rows",
                1,
                "minX",
                0.3515625,
                "maxX",
                5.2734375,
                "minY",
                51.50390625,
                "maxY",
                51.6796875,
                "counts_ints2D",
                [
                    // heatmap...
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The bounds in the 'facet_heatmaps' (minX, maxY...) are not equal to the bounds passed in 'params'. Is there a way to force Solr build headmap by specified bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is not a way to force a Solr facet heatmap facet response to equal the exact bounds that are passed in. The Solr facet heatmap response returns a faceted response based off of the facet counts of underlying prefix tree spatial grid implementation.

Try experimenting with changing the `distErrPct` values or switching the `prefixTree` to `grid` to obtain a finer grain response.

Source the Solr documentation:

> You’ll experiment with different distErrPct values (probably 0.10 - 0.20) with various input geometries till the default size is what you’re looking for. The specific details of how it’s computed isn’t important. For high-detail grids used in point-plotting (loosely one cell per pixel), set distErr to be the number of decimal-degrees of several pixels or so of the map being displayed. Also, you probably don’t want to use a geohash based grid because the cell orientation between grid levels flip-flops between being square and rectangle. Quad is consistent and has more levels, albeit at the expense of a larger index.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/spatial-search.html#SpatialSearch-HeatmapFaceting